# 'Split' integers in Terminal

Tags: ruby, printing, terminal, integer, fizzbuzz

In **Ruby**, I'm trying to solve a quiz as like a *FizzBuzz Challenge*. My question is "How I can print the integer number `|n|` adding a **comma and space**`(", ")`at the end of they?"

To separate the `Nama`and `Team` strings I'm using `$stdout.print "Team, " && $stdout.print "Nama, "`. But for the integers my syntax is `$stdout.print n`:

[image]

#### Code right now:

```
puts "Enter the maximum amount of numbers"
print ">"
upper_limit = gets.chomp.to_i

(1..upper_limit).each do |n|

  if n % 35  == 0
    $stdout.print "NamaTeam"

  elsif n % 7 == 0
    $stdout.print "Team, "

  elsif n % 5 == 0
    $stdout.print "Nama, "

  else
    $stdout.print n
  end
end
```

I already tried to use `.join(' ')` and `.split(' ')` methods but they don't work with `integer` numbers D:

Best Regards for the community!

Comment: @TomLord Awesome!! Worked 100% :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With string interpolation:

```
$stdout.print "#{n}, "
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity; another solution would be to *construct* the whole line by joining the array:

```
puts (1..35).map { |n| 
  if n % 35 == 0 then "NamaTeam"
  elsif n % 7 == 0 then "Team"
  elsif n % 5 == 0 then "Nama"
  else n end 
}.join(', ')
```